# Сформировать двумерный массив из неупорядоченного списка его элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив элементов(объекты, с координатами), из которого необходимо сформировать двумерный массив. Я решил это так (ход решения в коде):

```js
//список элементов двумерного массива
let rangeArr = [
{x:20, y:31},
{x:21, y:32},
{x:21, y:30},
{x:20, y:30},
{x:22, y:32},
{x:20, y:32},
{x:21, y:31},
{x:22, y:30},
{x:22, y:31},
];
let size = 3; //размер двумерного массива
let resultArr = [];

function getMap(){
let minX = getMinOs(rangeArr, "x");//определяю минимальное значение по X
let minY = getMinOs(rangeArr, "y");//определяю минимальное значение по Y
//формирую двумерный массив, который сразу сортирую по X
for (let i=0; i<size; i++){
 let f = [];
 resultArr.push(f);
 for (let h=0; h<size; h++){
  for (let k=0; k<rangeArr.length; k++){
   if (rangeArr[k].x == minX){
    resultArr[i].push(rangeArr[k]);
    rangeArr.splice(k,1);
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 minX++;
}
  //получившийся отсортированный массив по Х, сортирую по У
for (let i=0; i<resultArr.length; i++){
 resultArr[i].sort(sortFunction)
}
 console.log(resultArr);
}

function sortFunction(a,b){
if(a.y < b.y){
 return -1
} else {
 return 1
}
}


function getMinOs(arr, OS){
let min = arr[0][OS];
for (let i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
 if (arr[i][OS] < min){
  min = arr[i][OS];
 }
}
return min
}

getMap();
```

Как решить эту задачу элегантнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const rangeArr = [
{x:20, y:31},
{x:21, y:32},
{x:21, y:30},
{x:20, y:30},
{x:22, y:32},
{x:20, y:32},
{x:21, y:31},
{x:22, y:30},
{x:22, y:31},
]

const sorted = rangeArr.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x !== 0 ? a.x - b.x : a.y - b.y)
const result = []

let j = 0
for (const i in sorted) {
 if (void 0 !== sorted[i - 1] && sorted[i].x !== sorted[i - 1].x) {
  j++
 }

 if(void 0 === result[j]) {
  result.push([])
 }

 result[j].push(sorted[i])
}
console.log(result)
```

Как то так вышло.